# Java iterate over dynamic string

Tags: java, string, loops

Consider a string:

`<p>This is 1st paragraph</p>
 <p>This is 2nd paragraph</p>`

I want to append a string to the above string whenever `<` is found,
something like:

`HELLO<p>This is 1st paragraphHELLO</p>
 HELLO<p>This is 2nd paragraphHELLO</p>`

The problem is when I iterate over this string and append in it, the length of the above string changes and I keep on appending the string at the same position. How to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you're using that's leading to the incorrect result.

Comment: Why not just replace every `<` with your String and add the "<" back in? `originalString.replace("<", "HELLO<");`?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is, instead of iterating, just use string replacement:

```
String x = "<p>This is 1st paragraph</p>"
String y = x.replace("<", "HELLO<")
System.out.println(y)
// HELLO<p>This is 1st paragraphHELLO</p>
```

The problem with iterating is that your position in the string is fundamentally tied to the structure of the string itself. Thus, when you modify the structure of the string by adding or removing characters, your position in the string doesn't change - so it ends up in the spot where you don't want it to be. I don't know what method exactly you're using to iterate - as of writing this you haven't provided a code snippet of that - but if you really want to do this using iteration instead of using the `replace()` method, you need to be careful that every time you change the string, you also move the iterator according to the way you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't homework, you could just use String [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) to replace all occurrences of "<" with "HELLO<". If you have to do this yourself, then every time you insert some text you just have to add the length of the text you inserted to your loop counter